# changes in backbone model in child view does not show up in parent view

Tags: backbone.js, model

I am having a similar issue(as https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19889900) that the model passed to a subview only gets updated for that subview and the model in the parent view is not updated. 
@magulka: is your problem actually solved ?

Here is my code structure:

In my router.js :

```
var model = new campaignModel();
var parentView = new ParentView({model:model});
```

In my parent view:

```
var itemdetail = new itemdetailView({model:this.model});
```

In my child view itemdetail:

```
this.model.set("key","value");
```

Now if I check the value of model in parent view...the value set in child does not show up.
Any clue. I am not reinstantiating my model in any views. It was created once in the router.

Comment: let's see the initialize function of your parent view, maybe there is just a problem in passing the model in your code

Comment: Note: there's a rejected suggested edit that may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5622286

Answer (score 1):

Sorry.In my callback in parent had some mistake in getting values. So all is well. No problem. Backbone rocks!

Comment: If there are no problems you can always delete the question, like it never happened.